# Trigger to Create/Update Opportunity on Account Created

Tags: apex, trigger

When I create a new Account and set the Client_Account_Status field(Picklist) to 'Active', I want an opportunity field under the Account created to update a field 'Stage' with field name 'StageName'(Picklist) to 'Closed Won'.

But it isn't creating the Opportunity.

Here is my code

```
trigger createOpportunity on Account (after insert) {

List<Opportunity> oppsToUpdate = new List<Opportunity>();
// or whatever your custom object name put instead of Opportunity

for(Account ac : Trigger.new) {


    // here is where you check if opportunity that is being inserted
    //meets the criteria
    if (ac.Client_Account_Status__c == 'Active') {

    Opportunity o = new Opportunity (); //instantiate the object to put values for future record

    // now map opportunity fields to new vehicle object that is being created with this opportunity

    o.StageName = 'Closed Won'; 

    oppsToUpdate.add(o);


    }//end if

}//end for o

//once loop is done, you need to insert new records in SF
// dml operations might cause an error, so you need to catch it with try/catch block.
try {
    insert oppsToUpdate; 
} catch (system.Dmlexception e) {
    system.debug (e);
 }
}
```

If there could be another approach to solving this task, i'd love to hear it, please I'm a salesforce newbie.

Comment: You can use Process Builder to do this, no need to write a trigger.

Answer (score 1):

In Opportunity object three fields are required : Name, CloseDate, StageName. 
So, we need value for closeDate, name as well in trigger

```
trigger createOpportunity on Account (after insert) {

List<Opportunity> oppsToUpdate = new List<Opportunity>();
// or whatever your custom object name put instead of Opportunity

for(Account ac : Trigger.new) {


    // here is where you check if opportunity that is being inserted
    //meets the criteria
    if (ac.Type == 'Prospect') {

    Opportunity o = new Opportunity (); //instantiate the object to put values for future record

    // now map opportunity fields to new vehicle object that is being created with this opportunity

    o.StageName = 'Closed Won'; 
    o.CloseDate = Date.today();   
    o.Name = 'Opp';

    oppsToUpdate.add(o);


    }//end if

}//end for o

//once loop is done, you need to insert new records in SF
// dml operations might cause an error, so you need to catch it with try/catch block.

    insert oppsToUpdate; 

}
```

Comment: Because of validation rules in his org, other fields may be required as well. He should check to see what those are too, otherwise his records may fail on validation.